# Should there be a tag for the Baha'i Faith in Christianity Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask a question on the view of the Baha'i Faith regarding the Christian doctrine of original sin. However, there is no tag for the Baha'i Faith.

Is that because the Baha'i Faith is not considered to be Christian?  Yet they believe in the life and death of Jesus Christ and that his spirit ascended into heaven. They also claim to have the proper interpretation/context that makes sense out of some other Christian beliefs.

Be aware I neither condone nor condemn their religious beliefs - but how am I to do meaningful research into this religion and get answers to questions if there is no tag covering this religious denomination?

Comment: There doesn't currently seem to be any questions about the Baha'i Faith on Stack Exchange except for one on Islam.SE: [Are bahaism and babism counted as one of the branches of shiism?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18001/are-bahaism-and-babism-counted-as-one-of-the-branches-of-shiism) I've always seen it listed as a separate religion distinct from Christianity, Islam, Hinduism, etc. Even though they accept parts of each of those religions as true, they don't identify as any single one of those other religions.

Comment: @4castle - I found a couple of mentions of the Baha'i Faith (in answers) on Christianity Stack Exchange. Thanks for the link to the Islam section - I never thought to look there.

Comment: I hope there is a way to figure out how to entertain those questions that can relate to the Christian belief and Baha'i .  Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Baha'i is not Christian, and its adherents do not self identify as Christian AFAIK. But you can ask about them in a comparative religion type question.

You're free to make the tag yourself, but it may get automatically removed if there aren't more questions. Which isn't a problem. Tags don't determine whether a question is allowed.

Comment: Appreciate your input - I will ask the question and see what happens.